# Not able to connect to vpn in ubuntu. Web authentication required

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, cisco

Not able to connect to vpn in ubuntu. Web authentication required is being displayed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by selecting disable captive portal selection.
Go to any connect preferences and select disable captive portal selection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).